Using external artifact feed in Azure DevOps pipeline alongside the Azure project's own artifact feed
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline. I need to restore from two separate feeds, excluding nuget.org. The first is the artifact feed in the Azure project, and the other is an external artifactory feed from a JFrog source. I am having some trouble accomplishing it. The only way I can figure to do this, is to use a NuGet.Config file like so:
steps:
# Find and set NuGet.config file path to disco2000 variable
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=disco2000]$(Get-ChildItem $env:APPDATA/NuGet/NuGet.Config)"

# Add internal feed to NuGet.config
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Add internal Feed'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'sources Add -Name internal -Source https://internal/url/to/an/index.json -username anything -password $(System.AccessToken)'

# Add external feed to NuGet.config
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Add external Feed'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'sources Add -Name external -Source https://external/url/to/an/index.json -username $(feedUsername) -password $(feedPassword)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(disco2000)'

Both feedUsername and feedPassword come from an azure key vault. Adding the external feed manually like this is fine, it is only certain pipelines that need access to it, but the problem is that I then do not have access to the project's own artifact feed and the solution I've come to, adding it a separate task, feels like a hack to me.
Is there a better way of doing this?

You can add your external feed as an upstream source of the feed inside your project. See the detailed info from Set up upstream sources.


To consume packages from a Jfrog feed, you can use this extension JFrog, which supports downloading your build dependencies from Artifactory to the build agent. The downloaded dependencies are defined using File Specs. To use this extension, you need to create a "jfrog artifactory v2" service connection. Put in your Server URL, username, password, and service connection name. Verify connection, and save.

See more info about this extension from JFrog Azure DevOps Extension.

I apologise. You reminded me that I have left out some fairly crucial detail in my problem description. The external feed is from another source entirely. It is from a Jfrog feed. I looked at using upstreams as well, but, as far as I can see, once you go outside of Azure only public feeds are supported.

To consume packages from a Jfrog feed, you can use this extension JFrog, see my updated details above.
